# How to get the name or type of the Intent fired from onReceive()

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I need to create a `BroadcastReceiver` that listens for when the the phone receives or makes a call, so I can take note of when it started and when it ended. I realized that the two receivers will look almost the same so instead of creating two separate `BroadcastReceiver`s for incoming and for outgoing calls, I can just create one for both and make my actions depend on what event was fired.

I registered `intent-filter`s for `android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE` and `android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` in the manifest, but how do I find out from `onReceive()` what kind of `Intent` was fired?

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    // get the intent fired--incoming or outgoing call?
    // then, save it in a variable and perform corresponding actions
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just use intent.getAction();

```
String action=intent.getAction();

if(action.equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)){

//dosomething here
}
else if(action.equalsIgnoreCase(second action)){

//do something here
}
```

Comment: Any idea what the intent is for the incoming call?

Comment: Anyway, I printed out the `intent.getAction()` when it's an incoming call. Turns out to be `android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE`, but it's not one of the public constants of `Intent`, and the string itself might change in the future. In any case, since I'm only catching two events, I can just check for `ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` in an `if` statement, `else` it's none other than an incoming call event.

Answer (score 2):

Compare your action with `intent.getAction()` using `equals()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do one thing is to put one string parameter to bundle at the time of setting pending intent, that makes possible to know from which intent OnReceive calls.Also can use " intent.getAction() "
Hope it helps  :)